# Select Values Into One Column

Tags: mysql

I know in MySQL I can do this:

`SELECT (SELECT 1), (SELECT 'Foo')`

To produce this output:

```
#  | (SELECT 1) | (SELECT 'Foo')
-----------------------------
1  | 1          | Foo
-----------------------------
```

Is it possible to select the results in to separate rows?

The desired output

```
#  | Results
----------------
1  | 1          
----------------
2  | Foo
```

Comment: I think this is oversimplified..if you want the results from the sample data select 1 as results union all select foo and what do you mean by abitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Your original query is better written as

```
SELECT 1, 'Foo'
```

no need for subqueries.

To get them as rows you can use `UNION`

```
SELECT 1 AS Results
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Foo'
```

The difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is that `UNION` without `ALL` implies `DISTINCT`.

Comment: *The difference between UNION and UNION ALL is that UNION without ALL implies DISTINCT.* This is synthactical difference only (by the way, UNION and UNION DISTINCT are synonims). But there is a real difference - UNION [DISTINCT] performs additional hidden sorting process for to remove duplicates, so it is more expensive.